# ERROR: Found inconsistency in table HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We are using HBase 0.94.7 with two region servers. We have a region always in transition. When I do the `hbase hbck`, there are inconsistencies found. But neither `hbase hbck -repair` nor `hbase hbck -fix` would help because of this region in transition. Here is the log from `hbase hbck`

```
ERROR: Region { meta => LogTable,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01@\x07B\x02\xCF\xEF\xCE>.,1374573828457.f41ff2fae25d1dab3f16306f4f995369., hdfs => hdfs://master:8020/hbase/LogTable/f41ff2fae25d1dab3f16306f4f995369, deployed =>  } not deployed on any region server.
ERROR: There is a hole in the region chain between \x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01@\x07B\x02\xCF\xEF\xCE>. and \x00\x00\x01\xFC\x00\x00\x01@\x08\x1E1\x0F\x07&\xCE\x11.  You need to create a new .regioninfo and region dir in hdfs to plug the hole.
ERROR: Found inconsistency in table LogTable
ERROR: Found lingering reference file hdfs://master:8020/hbase/LogTable/f41ff2fae25d1dab3f16306f4f995369/l/d9c7d33257ae406caf8d94277ff6d247.fbda7904cd1f0ac9583e04029a138487
ERROR: Found lingering reference file hdfs://master:8020/hbase/LogTable/f41ff2fae25d1dab3f16306f4f995369/l/b4f4b4ba52f041d5b9ee03318cac7fb7.fbda7904cd1f0ac9583e04029a138487
ERROR: Found lingering reference file hdfs://master:8020/hbase/LogTable/f41ff2fae25d1dab3f16306f4f995369/l/ee7dd42b15fe4622882ec6a7a773e01f.fbda7904cd1f0ac9583e04029a138487
```

When I tried `hbase hbck -repair`, it loops infinitely because of the region in transition:

```
INFO util.HBaseFsckRepair: Region still in transition, waiting for it to become assigned: {NAME => 'LogTable'....}
```

I have no clue how to resolve this problem, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Merge <br/>
```

Usage:

```
bin/hbase merge [table-name] region-1 region-2
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you had a failed region split, see [HBASE-8052] (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8502) for more details.

This bug leaves references to parent regions that have been moved in HDFS.  To fix, just delete the reference files listed in the HBCK output e.g. `hadoop fs -rm hdfs://master:8020/hbase/LogTable/f41ff2fae25d1dab3f16306f4f995369/l/d9c7d33257ae406caf8d94277ff6d247.fbda7904cd1f0ac9583e04029a138487`.

Once the bad references are gone the region should be assigned automatically.  You may have to do the assignment from the shell, in my experience though it only takes a minute or two for the region to get reassigned.  Then run `hbase hbck -fix` again to confirm there are no other inconsistencies.

Comment: You are removing the region which means that data will be permanently lost!!